# In routes.rb, what does the "#" symbol mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In Ruby on Rails, what does the # symbol mean in the following:

```
root to: 'stores#index', as: 'store'
```

I've looked everywhere for an explanation, but just can't find anything! I'm sure it's quite simple.

Comment: Thanks all, great responses - I understand now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html), the 'stores#index' would redirect to `index` action of `stores` controller

Answer (score 2):

The # is used to denote that you are choosing the action (method) index from the controller (class) store. There's a little bit more to it than that, but essentially the store\index.html is routed to by the rails framework. This is part of the RESTful architecture.